# Loki Calendar summary - shifted one day

Tags: calendar

elementary OS 0.4 Loki (64-bit) - in Calendar there is a summary of daily events at the right side of the screen. The summary is shifted one day back in time i.e. on Thursday it shows the events on Wednesday, on Friday the events of Thursday are shown etc. I can not trace a good reason for this.